# Question about a derivation in Field theoretical bosonization (Page 178 Altland and Simons)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, commutator, bosonization

I'm now reading the 'Condensed Matter Field Theory' by Altland and Simons, Chapter4.3 on page 178, and having difficulties understanding the commutation relationship (4.47) (in my opinion, there should be a minus sign):
$$
[\hat{\phi}(x),\hat{\theta}(x^\prime)]=i\pi\Theta(x^\prime-x)\tag{4.47}
$$
where $\hat{\theta}(x)$ is the bosonic string variable:
$$
\hat{\theta}(x)=\pi\int_{-\infty}^xdx^\prime\hat{\rho}(x^\prime)
$$
and
$$
[\hat{\rho}(x),\hat{\phi}(x^\prime)]=i\delta(x-x^\prime).
$$

Comment: Where are the 2 last eqs from? Did you check the errata page?

Comment: @Qmechanic  ...on the top of page 177 we read : **Charge-density representations** of this type are frequently employed in bosonic theories. Importantly, the transformation $\left(b,b^\dagger\right)\longrightarrow(\hat\rho,\hat\phi)$ is canonical, i.e. the density and the phase of a bosonic excitation form a canonically conjugate pair, $[\hat\rho (x), \hat\phi(x')] = i\delta(x − x').^{20}$ (where 20 is a footnote in this same page).

Comment: ...while in the middle of the page : In fact, there is a certain ambiguity in the definition of the string variable: defining
$$\hat\theta(x)=\pi\int\limits_{-\infty}^x \mathrm dx^\prime\hat\rho(x^\prime),$$
it is straightforward to show that...